# Restarting Rails Server

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've inherited an existing Rails 2 application and am currently trying to deploy it on production servers.

As a rails/unix novice, what's the best way to find out what webserver the rails application is running on and how can I restart the server. (since from what I've read, rails will cache everything on production servers)

The previous developer used Capistrano, but unfortunately I don't have access to the GIT repository.

I noticed /configuration/deploy.rb has the following lines:

```
desc "Custom restart task for mongrel cluster"
task :restart, :roles => :app, :except => { :no_release => true } do
  deploy.mongrel.restart
end

desc "Custom start task for mongrel cluster"
task :start, :roles => :app do
  deploy.mongrel.start
end

desc "Custom stop task for mongrel cluster"
task :stop, :roles => :app do
  deploy.mongrel.stop
end
```

Does this imply mongrel_rails is being used?

If so what's the best way to restart the application to pick up my changes?

Many thanks.

Comment: Note: I have FTP and SSH access to the web server

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Does this imply mongrel_rails is being
>   used?

Yes.

> If so what's the best way to restart
>   the application to pick up my changes?

It depends on which Application server you currently use. Assuming the current recipe is ok, simply call the Capistrano restart task.

```
$ cap deploy:restart
```

Comment: When I run this commmand, I get command not found.  Seeing how it was previously managed by Capistrano, I assume I am missing a path variable or does each user have their own instance of capistrano?

Comment: Did you install Capistrano on your computer?

Comment: I didn't manage to get Capistrano installed on my computer as my deployment time was limited.  I ended up uploading the files via FTP and touching /tmp/restart.txt as I checked the installed gems, and passenger was installed.  Thanks for the help.